# TabBar Fixed Container Shadow goes down of ListView while scrolling vertically in flutter

Tags: css, flutter, listview, flutter-layout, elevation

I want to add a bit shadow to my Container, which I have done using **Material Widget** or **BoxShadow** but in column at bottom of fixed container I have expanded Listview when I scroll up vertically container shadow goes down of Listview which I do not want I want Shadow to appear on top of ListView Items as we Scroll vertically , That's all please help me out

...Here is my code

```
Material(
              elevation: 2,
               child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      blurRadius: 2,
                      spreadRadius: 2,
                      offset: Offset(0,2),


                    ),


                  ],
                ),
                height: SizeConfig.isLargeScreen ? 60.h : 105.h,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: !SizeConfig.isLargeScreen),),
```

**Note**: I have given elevation 3 to my Listview card as well, Please let me know what i can do to make this container shadow go above  Listview while Scrolling Vertically

Comment: Would you be able to add a screenshot or a GIF to explain this?

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess this can be solved by using padding widget, know more about the padding widget in ( https://youtu.be/oD5RtLhhubg ).
2. Another way to handle the issue adding a listView with separator, divider.
3. Still the problem continues check with margin of the container.
4. Finally on top of all since this is about container shadow you can try with the offset value in boxshadow property.
5. share with us, which method helps you to solve the issue or how did you solved the issue by trying something different.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to solve this issue
the first one is to wrap your **Material widget** with **Padding widget** like this:

```
Padding(
    Material(
          elevation: 2,
           child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  blurRadius: 2,
                  spreadRadius: 2,
                  offset: Offset(0,2),


                ),


              ],
            ),
            height: SizeConfig.isLargeScreen ? 60.h : 105.h,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: !SizeConfig.isLargeScreen),),),
```

or simply add `SizedBox(height: 20,),` under the **Material widget** it will make some space between the **Material widget** and the **ListView** then it will solve your issue